# Dealing with high frequency tokens during masked Language modelling?

Tags: machine-learning, language-model, imbalanced-data, masking

Suppose I am working with a Masked Language Model to pre-train on a specific dataset. In that dataset, most sequences have a particular token of a high frequency

```
Sample Sequence:-
<tok1>, <tok1>, <tok4>, <tok7>, <tok4>, <tok4> ---> here tok4 is very frequent in this sequence
```

So if I mask some tokens and get the model to train to predict those masked tokens, obviously the model will gain a bias in predicting `<tok4>` due to its statistical frequency.

Since `<tok4>` represents important information, 'downsampling' (or removing those frequent tokens) would not be preferred and I would love to have my sequence as intact as possible.

How best should I deal with this? Is there any already established method that can counter this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The goal of language modeling is to build a statistical model of how language is used in a specific context. One of the important components of that is token frequency.

Bias can mean many things in machine learning. I think you bias in the sense of high chance of prediction. That kind of bias is useful in language modeling. If `<tok4>` appears frequently, a useful language model will capture that property.

Comment: sure, but if we want to reduce the bias?

Comment: Add a back-off model https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katz%27s_back-off_model